# Why phase response returns different values for Sliding DFT(1440 degrees for N=32 and f= 40kHz) and r-Sliding DFT and goertzel (0 degree)

Tags: matlab

While simulating the SDFT ,rSDFT and Goertzel DFT i got phase responses to be different for SDFT and rSDFT. As Goertzel and rSDFT have are derived from same SDFT structure why there is so much difference in phase response values. Although warping phase gives same graph but i am interested in absolute values.[image: the MATLAB returns the phase represented in figure]

Comment: If you’re implementing an SDFT in a real-world application, you should definitely review "Improvements to the Sliding DFT Algorithm", DSP Tips & Tricks column, IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, Vol. 38, No. 4, July 2021. Or visit the following web page: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352874961_Improvements_to_the_Sliding_Discrete_Fourier_Transform_Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

I dunno exactly what each of these algorithms do for [phase unwrapping](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/fp/Phase_Unwrapping.html).  Unfortunately a sorta standard of expression for polar coordinates has developed in that the magnitude must always be real **and** non-negative.

$$ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\Big\{x(t)\Big\} = \big| X(f) \big| \, e^{i \phi(f)} $$

where we know that $|X(f)|\ge 0$  When $|X(f)|$ has a zero-crossing, then $\phi$ has a jump discontinuity of $\pi$ radians.

So I would propose a polar notation with a bipolar magnitude:

$$ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\Big\{x(t)\Big\} =  \hat{X}(f) \, e^{i \hat{\phi}(f)} $$

where $\hat{X}(f) \in \mathbb{R}$, $|\hat{X}(f)| = |X(f)|$ (which means $\hat{X}(f) = \pm |X(f)|$), and

$$ \hat{\phi}(f) = \phi(f) + \pi n(f)  $$

and $n(f) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\hat{\phi}(0) = 0$ and $\hat{\phi}(f)$ is as continuous as your gonna get.

This gets the polarity at DC figured into $\hat{X}(f)$.

Haven't thought of how to formalize this.  It's just been sorta eating at me.